# Angular: showing a loading image on http requests

Tags: angularjs

My objective is to intercept http requests/responses to show/hide a loading image. Since I may have more than one http request when a page is loaded, I use a counter. The problem is that the image never shows up.

This is the interceptor

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q,$rootScope) {

    var counter = 0;
    $rootScope.loading = false;

    var seeCounter = function(i) {
        counter += i;
        if (i > 0) {
            $rootScope.loading = true;
        }
        else {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
        }
    };   

    return {
        request: function(config) {
            seeCounter(1);
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            seeCounter(-1);
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function(rejection) {
           seeCounter(-1);
           return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

and this is the HTML of the web page:

```
<img style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;z-index:30000;" 
        src="loading-image.gif" ng-show="loading" />
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted to check `if (counter > 0)` rather than `if (i > 0)`?

Comment: try if (counter > 0)

Comment: thanks, that was the problem